What frequencies can crocodile (alligator) probes carry?
When measuring with an oscilloscope, I use an original high frequency oscilloscope probe and a double side crocodile (alligator) clip and the results are usually very close.
Note: it is called crocodile or alligator. I'm not sure which is more correct, I'm talking about a cable with a BNC connector with a crocodile end on both + and - ends.
I'm talking about standard croc clip like the one below.

What I want to know is up to how many MHz the alligator probes are reliable. And are there other reasons or scenarios not to use alligator probes? Is it right to measure with them? What are the limits? Is there a source that can be referred to on this? I could not find a source about this, and there is no such information from any sellers.

You should link to a certain croc clip cable product with some specs. There's many different kinds of croc clip leads for scopes.

also ask one question

I want to know is up to how many MHz the alligator probes are reliable If you can't define exactly what you mean by "reliable" - what measurement error you accept - then there's no question at all. No measurements are perfect, no probe techniques are perfect. They all come with errors. The question is - how much error can you accept. Also, the crocodile-terminated probes can be x1, x2, x5, x10, x100 just like other scope probes. This voltage division factor together with source impedance will affect the fidelity of measurement. So there's no general answer possible really.

standard croc clip like the one below You're showing the common x1 croc clip probe, but that's not a particularly good design. Much better croc probes can be made by having an isolated differential probe amplifier, and two shielded cables going to the crocs, with a 1:10 divider tucked inside each croc clip. They can work OK for qualitative evaluation switched power supplies, so bandwidths of 10s of MHz. You won't buy those on Aliexpress though. And those croc clips are not the best for use with small circuits. You'd want much smaller clip probes. Like... small oscilloscope probes :)

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I guess it can't be a technical data. I just want to learn about the experiences of those who have done tests with such corcs. What levels they were able to go up to, what error rates they saw at which levels. I guess there must be someone who has tested and experienced them, so we can have an idea about how reliable they are at what level and up to what level they can be used.
